# How do i display a textview over a button with custom layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, wear-os

How do i display a textview over a custom Button (that uses a png from res/drawable)?

I am trying to create a UI for a wearable square watch for android wear.
I created custom backgrounds to change the look of the two buttons that i want the layout to consist of.
When i add a textview to the layout, it is always placed under the Button, and never visible.

I have already searched for solutions, but usually the problem is that people are using the wrong layout. I have tried both frame and relative layout, which should both stack its content on top of each other, but doesn't.

Although i could use the text field in the button itself, i would rather have a dedicated textview for the text written inside. But i just can't figure out what the problem is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/wearable_alarm_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/red_button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
        android:id="@+id/wearable_timer_button"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" />
</FrameLayout>
```

[image: .]

Comment: share your blue and red button as well

Comment: not sure why you'd want it. 
[red_button](http://imgur.com/utv57zB)
[blue_button](http://imgur.com/iWKNvGR)

Answer (score 1):

add  tag after  tags like

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/wearable_alarm_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/red_button"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
    android:id="@+id/wearable_timer_button"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

It will show your textview above the Buttons.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. Do you mean using the stacking properties of the framelayout? This does not fix the problem either, i have tried putting it before and after the buttons.
And putting your example code into my xml file does not fix the problem either.